# Fill GridLayout cells with ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I have a GridLayout and I'm setting it's number of columns and rows programmatically. Then I want to fill these cells with imageView. So, how can I create enought ImageViews to fill all cells?

Here's part of my xml for GridLayout

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/dgLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        />
</GridLayout>
```

And here's the part of code from my activity class

```
dgLayout.setColumnCount(dwInt);
dgLayout.setRowCount(dhInt);
```

Comment: can you please post your code here

Comment: most likely in a loop, and keep the references in an array.